# Nearby cycles and specialisation - properties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules, sheaf-theory, constructible-sheaves, vanishing-cycles

I am looking for reference for properties of nearby cycles - specifically, commutation with non-characteristic pull-back (good enough - commutation with pull-back to closed subvariety which is transversal to a stratification for which our sheaf is smooth). I would like a reference for any of the following settings:

- D-modules using V-filtration or Beilinsons definition
- l-adic sheaves
- constructible sheaves in the "usual complex world"

Thank you,
Sasha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first item, section 3 of M. Saito's *Modules de Hodge Polarizables* is pretty thorough. He works in the filtered $D$-module setting, but I suppose you can ignore that aspect. For the constructible setting, perhaps you can look at Dimca's *Sheaves in Topology*.